# Changing text and plots with selected input in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to change the text in the box depending on what parameter is selected for the plot. So that **text and plot change at the same time**

So in that working example:

I wish to have the textoutput: "bliblablub" if the dropdown menu selects Sepal.width.

I wish to have the textoutput: "some text" if the dropdown menu selects Sepal.Length.

I wish to have the textoutput: "complete different stuff" if the dropdown menu selects Petal.Length.

I wish to have the textoutput: "new stuff" if the dropdown menu selects Petal.Width.

As I have in my original dataframe 15 parameters, I would love to get tips to handle the text input for each parameter as well. Ideally I would take the text from a second dataframe (having the same columnnames?).

So far I did not understand how to combine select Input, a textbox and a plotbox.

Thanks a lot for any help!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
#data
dat <-iris

#producing parameters for select input
param <- colnames(dat)
param <- param[1:4]


#ui
Header<- dashboardHeader(title = "Iris")

Sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Parametro", tabName = "parametro", icon = icon("car"))
  )
)

Body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "parametro",
            column(width = 12,
                   box(
                     plotOutput("boxplot_species")),
                   fluidRow(
                     box(
                       selectInput("parametro", "Parametros:",
                                   param), width = 6),
                     box(
                       textOutput("description"))
                   )    
            ))
  ))

ui <- dashboardPage(Header,
                    Sidebar,
                    Body)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$description <- renderText({
    "bliblablub"
  })
  output$boxplot_species <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(dat) +
      aes(x = Species, fill = Species) +
      aes_string(y = input$parametro) +
      geom_boxplot()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `switch` to update the text based on dropdown selection and replace `aes_string` with `.data` since `aes_string` is deprecated.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)

Header<- dashboardHeader(title = "Iris")

Sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Parametro", tabName = "parametro", icon = icon("car"))
  )
)

Body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "parametro",
            column(width = 12,
                   box(
                     plotOutput("boxplot_species")),
                   fluidRow(
                     box(
                       selectInput("parametro", "Parametros:",
                                   param), width = 6),
                     box(
                       textOutput("description"))
                   )    
            ))
  ))

ui <- dashboardPage(Header,
                    Sidebar,
                    Body)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$description <- renderText({
    text <- switch(input$parametro,
            Sepal.Length = 'x', 
            Sepal.Width = 'y',
            Petal.Length = 'other',
            Petal.Width  = 'more'
    )
    paste(text, "is blabla")
  })
  output$boxplot_species <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(dat) +
      aes(x = Species, y = .data[[input$parametro]], fill = Species) +
      geom_boxplot()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

---

To keep the code clean you can also create a lookup dataframe with `Species` and corresponding value.

```
lookup_df <- data.frame(Species = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"), 
                        value = c('x', 'y', 'other', 'more'))
```

Then change the `description` code to -

```
 output$description <- renderText({
    lookup_df$value[match(input$parametro, lookup_df$Species)]
  })
```

Comment: A thanks! But then my question was a bit misleading. I want the text to vary completly- so the textinput need to be stored somewhere else. So e.g. for Petal.Length: "x", Petal.Width: "y", Sepal.Length:"Z" and Sepal.Width:"something else"

Comment: @Annika Check the updated answer.

Comment: ok no I think I have to update de question... forget about "is blabla". The text for each parameter is completly different. The textoutput for Sepal.Width could be "It is part of a flower" and the textoutput for Sepal.Length: "Merry Christmas". It just changes with the drop downmenu.

Comment: @Annika That is what my answer is doing. If you don't want `"is blabla"` just remove it. Replace `paste(text, "is blabla")` with just `text`. In `switch` you change the text according to what you want for each `Species`. I have used `x`, `y`, `other` and `more` you can replace it with `bliblablub`, `"some text"` and so on. Have you tried it ?

Comment: you are right! thanks  a lot!

Comment: as mentioned in the question- is there a way to store the text in a "external dataframe" to keep the dashboard code clean? By trying this i get an error: Error in cat: argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'

Comment: I have updated the answer to use dataframe @Annika